# PHP, jQuery passing JSON array turns to object, how to keep it an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a PHP array, that I want to pass over to jQuery and update the rows on the page.

This PHP array is the 'name' of the checkboxes selected on the page.  (So this array can be of any length, depending on what the user selects)

PHP Array:

```
var_dump($sr->conflict_return);

OUTPUT CHECK: array(5) { [0]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_102_905_925" [1]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_101_905_925" [2]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_103_905_925" [4]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_104_845_915" [13]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_103_845_905" }
```

This this case... there are '5' elements in my [php] array.

Here is where my problem comes into play...

Sometimes it 'works'... sometimes it doesnt..

The 'key' seems to be what is IN the array:

```
OUTPUT CHECK: array(3) { [0]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_102_845_905" [1]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_101_845_905" [2]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_104_845_915" }
```

this seems to work.. 3 items in array.. all 3 rows on stage get highlighted.

this:

```
OUTPUT CHECK: array(4) { [0]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_102_845_905" [1]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_101_845_905" [2]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_103_845_905" [4]=> string(33) "hours_9_7_reg_session_104_845_915" }
```

doesnt work... and none of the rows are highlighted

(seems like if there is 4 items in the array it breaks??)

my jQuery to parse the data:

```
var conflictItems = <?=json_encode($sr->conflict_return); ?>;   
//has a conflict list
    if(conflictItems.length > 0){   
        alert("Has conflicts");
        //loop through and highlight elements on stage
        for(i=0; i<conflictItems.length; i++){
            console.log(conflictItems[i]);
            $("#sr_table_"+conflictItems[i]+"_row").addClass("conflict_border");
        }
    }
```

When I trace (console.log()) the data....  I get odd results.

```
console.log('CONFLICT ITEMS: ' + conflictItems);
console.log('CONFLICT COUNT: ' + conflictItems.length);
```

3 x items in array...  the above shows:

```
CONFLICT ITEMS: hours_9_7_reg_session_103_845_905,hours_9_7_reg_session_102_845_905,hours_9_7_reg_session_104_845_915
CONFLICT COUNT: 3
```

which to me is correct.  I have 3 items in my array passed over from PHP..jQuery runs through list and adds a class to each 'row'.

however, when I add a 4th item...   the traced output is:

```
CONFLICT ITEMS: [object Object]
CONFLICT COUNT: undefined
```

So how?  is my array turning into an object?.. and more so WHY??

and how can I fix this?  I dont understand why having 3 items in the array works.. but not 4?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have non-sequential arrays, thus PHP encodes it as an object.

Comment: @JonStirling good catch - you should probably post that as an answer!

Comment: hint: `array_values()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have a concept of non-sequential array keys (your example has keys 0,1,2 and 4), thus when running `json_encode` on the array, it converts it to JSON notation for a JS object.

As @Kenney says in the comments, a possible solution is to keep using arrays, but make use of `array_values()` function which takes your array, and basically regenerates the array dropping the existing keys and using sequential ones.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing index 3 from your array, therefore js turns it into an object.

Comment: ok.. thanks for the replies, and explanation, but then how DO I parse my array (object) correctly.. with what I have above?

For full disclosure,...  the missing indices are a results of me trying to rid my array of duplicates:

`$uniquePresentations = array_unique($presentations); `

If I did nt do this... and just left the dups in... I wouldnt have this problem I take it?  (still for clean data, I'd like to keep the non-dup array, and figure out how to work with the object I guess)

Comment: You can reset you array keys like this: $arr =array_values($arr);

Comment: Thanks guys!   I'm not sure who to give credit to?  @Jon Stirling explained WHY it wasnt working.  (which is good to know)

but Kenny mentioned the array_values(), which IMHO was really the "FIX" (answer)